# Trigger Apps Scripts function on Fixed Range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to run the following function based on when a edit is made in a fixed range:

```
  function onSelectionChange(e){
  e.range = 'A9:P32'
  payoutToSheet()

}
```

This does not work.  Is it possible to trigger an event on a fixed range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart < 17 && e.range.rowStart > 8 && e.range.rowStart < 33) {
    payoutToSheet()
  }
}
```

Event Object Sample: `{"authMode":"LIMITED","range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":6,"rowEnd":5,"rowStart":5},"source":{},"user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}`

if you wish to specify a sheet you can use `const sh = e.range.getSheet();if(sh.getName() == 'SheetName'){//rest of stuff in here};`

Comment: Got it to work.  Looks like I need onEdit(e).

Comment: Yeah I didn't see the onEdit() in your question.  It shouldn't make any difference they both have the required info in the event objects.

Comment: Whenever you dealing with these triggers it's handy to see the event object with `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`  That way you can see the entire event object not just the documented part.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can specify within your code if it is within a range, then execute something. See below will run code if top left cell changed is 32 or less for row and less than column 16.

Example

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getCells(1, 1).getRow() <= 32 && range.getCells(1, 1).getColumn() <= 16) {
    payoutToSheet()
  }
}
```